# Communicate over UART in linux driver

Tags: linux-device-driver

I need to implement a linux driver that communicates to a MCU over UART but since we already have a UART driver I am wondering how can I have a driver that communicates through the UART driver?

This seems to be common to do with I2C but I can't find any information about anyone doing it with UART.

/Stefan

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to define the API to your remote device by using syscalls.  You would be better off by layering your software; it would then be portable.  You cannot compare with I2C or SPI since both master and slave devices are expected to be installed on the same board.  Take a look at how SLIP uses the serial port.

Comment: There's one instance of a mainline (albeit staging) driver that uses a UART driver in the kernel, [serial2002_open()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/staging/comedi/drivers/serial2002.c#L550), which is part of the Comedi project.